# Which Spark ML Feature Transformer should I use to convert a column of phrases to vectors of fixed length?

Tags: apache-spark, tokenize, apache-spark-mllib, one-hot-encoding

Let us say that I have a Spark DataFrame where one of the column has short phrases. The total number of unique phrases is too large to be useful in a machine learning algorithm, but I was thinking of breaking the phrases into words and then transforming each phrase into a vector of fixed length `N` where each dimension indicates if one of the `N` most common words is found in this phrase.

Here's an example.

```
val sentenceDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (0, "Foo bar dinosaur"),
  (1, "bar logistic"),
  (2, "foo bar logistic regression")
)).toDF("id", "sentence")
```

If I let `N` be 3, then I expect the following transformed DataFrame

```
val sentenceDataFrameTransformed = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (0, "Foo bar dinosaur", [1, 1, 0]),
  (1, "bar logistic", [0, 1, 0]),
  (2, "foo bar logistic regression", [1 1 1])
)).toDF("id", "sentence", "sentenceTopWordsHotEncoded")
```

The top words would be "foo," "bar," and "logistic" in this case (by the popularity).

There are a lot of available transformers that [Spark describes here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#feature-transformers), but I don't see one (or an easy combination of some) that give me what I want.

The reason that I don't want to write this function manually is because I want the transformer ready to be put into a Pipeline so that I can serialize this model and so when I evaluate new rows, the top `N` words will be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either `CountVectorizer` or `HashingTF`. If you want binary features you should use the second one and `setBinary`.

Both will require tokenization first and optionally `StopWordsRemover`. Overall:

```
 (RegexTokenizer|Tokenizer) ->  (CountVectorizer|HashingTF)
```